# Changing date query from month

Tags: functions, date

I have been perfecting this bit of code below and ran into an issue. I was wondering how I can change the following code so that it will so the anniversary of any user in the next 30 days, not just by month (i.e, an anniversary on Jan. 15 would appear on my list on Dec. 15, not just once it was January)

Any suggestions (I'm running into such trouble because if I change the date sorting, I am not able to collect the correct user anniversary dates)

```
 $args = array(      
'meta_key' => 'anniversary_date',    
 'meta_value' => 0,  
 );   
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );  
 $users = $user_query->get_results();   

 foreach( $users as $user ):     
echo $user->display_name;   
 echo ' will be celebrating their anniversary on ';      
echo get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'anniversary_date', true );    
 endforeach;
```

---

```
function anniversary_user_query( $query ){   

 if( $query->query_vars['meta_key'] == 'anniversary_date' && $query->query_vars['meta_value'] === 0 ):     
     global $wpdb;         
     $thismonth = date('m');       
     $query->query_where = "WHERE 1=1 AND ( $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = 'anniversary_date' AND ( MONTH( $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value ) = $thismonth ) )";     
endif;    
return $query; 
 }  
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'anniversary_user_query' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm kinda confused on why you're passing 0 as meta_value, but if your storing unix timestamps under `anniversary_date`, this approach should be sufficient:

```
// queries anniversary dates between today and the next 30 days
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key' => 'anniversary_date',
        'meta_value' => array(strtotime('today'), strtotime('+30 days')),
        'meta_compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks, i plugged that in in place of  `$thismonth = date('m');             $query->query_where = "WHERE 1=1 AND ( $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = 'anniversary_date' AND ( MONTH( $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value ) = $thismonth ) )";      endif; ` but it doesn't seem to be working, any suggestions? Thanks so much!